# Bitrix, Rss парсинг и запись в инфоблоки

Tags: php, ajax, битрикс

CMS 1c bitrix, c ним почти не работал. Необходимо реализовать функционал парсинга rss ленты и записи категорий и их новостей в инфоблок,  при етом чтоб его можна использовать в качесте агента и ajax обновления. Начал писать компонент, использую клас CIBlockRSS для получения ленты. Хотел функционал реализовать в виде класса, только его нельзя использовать в компоненте.
1. Как реализовать без дублирования кода функционал обновления списка новостей через ajax?
2. Как с помощью Api создавать категории и инфоблоки?

Comment: 1. Не совсем понятен вопрос. Какой код дублировать и зачем? Выполняете аякс запрос к своему скрипту и получаете новые данные, дозаписываете

Comment: "Хотел функционал реализовать в виде класса, только его нельзя использовать в компоненте" это почему?

Comment: с классом разобрался,  открытым остается вопрос, как мне отдавать json ответа с новостями,для етого сделать отдельный шаблон и его запрашивать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу формирования JSON ответа. Болванка файла будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<?
define("NO_KEEP_STATISTIC", true);
define("NO_AGENT_STATISTIC", true); 
require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php');

// $arResult = здесь код получения списка новостей. Зависит от знаний
// и умений возможно достаточно \Bitrix\Iblock\ElementTable::getList()
// или просто подключаете компонент (например bitrix:niews.line), и в result_modifier.php формируете 
// желаемый формат массива и переносите туда нижеследующий код

$APPLICATION->RestartBuffer();
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arResult);
die();
```

2 Дока: [CIBlockSection::Add()](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblocksection/add.php) , [CIblockElement::Add()](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/add.php)